# Insert Decimal After Character Match in Text File

Tags: regex, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that has some data values. I need to insert a decimal point after the second character when the string has 3 values and after the third character when the string has 4 values.

**CSV File:**

```
956,938,987,964,1004,934,1018,912
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1./g"
```

**Current Result:**

```
95.6,93.8,98.7,96.4,10.04.,93.4,10.18.,91.2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
95.6,93.8,98.7,96.4,100.4,93.4,101.8,91.2
```

My current code (using `sed`) appears to be working for 3-value strings but, failing when it detects 4-value strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture 2 or more digits into 1 group, and then capture a trailing digit into another group:

```
s='956,938,987,964,1004,934,1018,912'
echo $s | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2,\}\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EbC3nc), output: `95.6,93.8,98.7,96.4,100.4,93.4,101.8,91.2`.

**Details**:

- `\([0-9]\{2,\}\)` - Group 1: two or more (`\{2,\}`) digits (`[0-9]`)
- `\([0-9]\)` - Group 2: a single digit.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply replacing

```
\B([0-9])\b
```

with

```
.\1
```

like

```
sed 's/\B\([0-9]\)\b/.\1/g'
```

Explanation:

`\B`          Matches if the position being match is **in** a word/number sequence (not a word boundary)
`([0-9])` Matches **and** captures a digit
`\b`          Matches if the position being match is in **on** a word/number boundary

By your examples I gather you simply want to have all numbers with one decimal. What this regex does is to match, and capture, the last digit in a multi digit number. Replacing it with itself preceded by a `.` gives you the desired output.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/DwjiBQ) and [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/01MVHS/2) for a more visual illustration.

**Edit**

If Wiktors concerns are an issue, change it to

```
\B([0-9])([0-9])\b
```

replaced by

```
\1.\2
```

like

```
sed 's/\B\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\b/\1.\2/g'
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/01MVHS/4).

Comment: `(\d)\b` will also add `.` in case of `1`. It will output `.1` and OP needs to only add the `.` in case a number has 3+ digits (at least I understand it like this). `\B(\d)\b` will add a `.` inbetween `2` and `4` in `24` (`2.4`) - again, not sure it is what OP expects.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True. Fixed :)

Comment: Not sure, I updated the comment. Besides, `$1` is not used in `sed`. The notation is `\1`.

Comment: please avoid online regex sites for questions on sed/awk/grep/etc... there are many differences in regex flavor used.. for ex: `\d` won't work with `sed`, need to use `[0-9]` instead... also `\b` and `\B` is specific to `GNU sed`, not available with other implementations

Comment: @Sundeep The links to online testers can be used to show how the regex works, but it goes without saying it is not a *proof* that the pattern will work in the target environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree, it could be used to show demonstration.. but this answer shows why it brings trouble... `\d` is simple enough to be replaced with `[0-9]` but I've seen answers using PCRE kinda features like lookarounds.. many questions as well using online regex sites and asking why it doesn't work with sed/awk/grep/etc...

Comment: @Sundeep Being a *Windows dude* I did not know as much. Changed to at least being `sed` compatible (since that was used as an example in the question). Tested and working :)

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.(,|$)/,".&")}1' file
95.6,93.8,98.7,96.4,100.4,93.4,101.8,91.2
```

Just in case if there was spaces or other stuff, you could:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[0-9] *(,|$)/,".&")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are just **dividing all numbers by 10**, hence you can use this **non-regex** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i/=10} 1' file

95.6,93.8,98.7,96.4,100.4,93.4,101.8,91.2
```

Comment: idea is good, but I think you need to print in specific format... for ex: `echo '3453535235' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i/=10} 1'` gives `3.45354e+08`

Comment: Also, `echo 1000 | awk ...` outputs 100. Depending on OP's needs that might be a good thing.